# google map api build failed

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-developer-api

```
* Exception is:
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/variant/AndroidComponentsExtension
at com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets_gradle_plugin.SecretsPlugin.apply(SecretsPlugin.kt:43)
at com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets_gradle_plugin.SecretsPlugin.apply(SecretsPlugin.kt:33)

Answer (score 1):

I solved that error, downgrading google secret plugin classpath from 2.0.0 to 1.3.0

```
        classpath("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:1.3.0")
```